# Ned the correct jQuery syntax to add an id to a Div

Tags: jquery

jQuery is creating a div like this

```
document.write("<div class='post' id=''>");
document.write(postcontent);
document.write(json.feed.entry[i].id.$t);
document.write('</div>');
```

But I want to move (json.feed.entry[i].id.$t) into the id of the div like this

```
document.write("<div class='post' id='(json.feed.entry[i].id.$t)'>");
document.write(postcontent);
document.write('</div>');
```

Cant get the syntax right as the above example does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not handled the quotes correctly while setting id value. use:

```
document.write("<div class='post' id='"+json.feed.entry[i].id.$t+"'>");
document.write(postcontent);
document.write('</div>');
```

You can also narrow down document.write to be used only once:

```
document.write("<div class='post' id='" + json.feed.entry[i].id.$t + "'>" + postcontent + "</div>");
```

Comment: @MarkL: something like this `document.write("<div class='post' id='post" + json.feed.entry[i].id.$t.split('post')[1] + "'>" + postcontent + "</div>");`

Comment: Excellent ;-) I actually removed that question just after I added and was going to ask it as a new question but you replied super fast ;-)

Fantastic thanks

Answer (score 1):

You arent concatenating correctly. Do it this way:

```
document.write("<div class='post' id='"+(json.feed.entry[i].id.$t)+"'>");
```